# df.groupby('columns').apply(''.join()), join all the cells to a string

Tags: pandas

`df.groupby('columns').apply(''.join())`, join all the cells to a string.

This is for a junior `dataprocessor`. In the past, I've tried many ways.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'key':['a','b','c','a','b','c','a'], 'profit': 
[12,3,4,5,6,7,9],'income':['j','d','d','g','d','t','d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(‘key’)
#df2 is expected result
data2 = {'a':['12j5g9d'],'b':['3d6d'],'c':['4d7t']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2 = df2.set_index(‘key’)
```

Comment: both look same, except `df2=df.reset_index()`

Comment: Your question is unclear and your code does not look like it has been properly pasted. Please, edit your question and make it answerable.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved couple different ways:

First add an extra column by concatenating the `profit` and `income` columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'key':['a','b','c','a','b','c','a'], 'profit': 
[12,3,4,5,6,7,9],'income':['j','d','d','g','d','t','d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('key')
df['profinc']=df['profit'].astype(str)+df['income']
```

1) Using [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
df2=df.groupby('key').profinc.sum()
```

2) Using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
df2=df.groupby('key').profinc.apply(''.join)
```

Results from both of the above would be the same:

```
key
a    12j5g9d
b       3d6d
c       4d7t
```

Comment: Your solution does not match the expected output of the question.

Comment: @Mattias I agree with you, unless you take the question without questionning it. The last line with `df2 = ...` uses `data` instead of `data2`.

Comment: @IMC that is true, the question needs to be edited and clarified such that it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah，sorry for that.

Comment: @Todd if it works you can hit that green button to mark it answered! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution, where we first translate the integers to strings and then concatenate profit and income, then finally we concatenate all strings under the same key:

```
data = {'key':['a','b','c','a','b','c','a'], 'profit':
    [12,3,4,5,6,7,9],'income':['j','d','d','g','d','t','d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['profit_income'] = df['profit'].apply(str) + df['income']
res = df.groupby('key')['profit_income'].agg(''.join)
print(res)


output:
   key
   a    12j5g9d
   b       3d6d
   c       4d7t
   Name: profit_income, dtype: object
```